# How do you manipulate tags in docker registry 2.0 and the v2 API?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Now that V1 of the docker registry is being deprecated, we started up a v2 private repo without much todo. The problem has been that we have relied on a number of v1 APIs to manage tags for deployments.

As of now we can easily list tags:

```
> curl https://repo-dns:5000/username/reponame/tags/list
```

But deleting a tag seems to include more than the tag and it appears to fail:

```
> curl -X DELETE https://repo-dns:5000/v2/username/reponame/manifests/tagtodelete
{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}
```

It is also unclear how to add a new tag - it used to go something like:

```
> echo my_image_id |curl -X PUT https://repo-dns:5000/v1/repositories/username/reponame/tags/newtag
```

I've looked at the [API docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), but its unclear how to do this.

Is it going to be possible to ADD and REMOVE tags going forward and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet implemented to delete tags - as far as I can tell from this issue: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/422